# Organizing/optimizing logic in ansible playbooks

Tags: ansible

I have the below ansible playbook. It does its job but I would like to know if can be improved regarding maintenance, redundancy, readability, formatting etc.

I am a bit concerned that my current approach will result in some huge messy playbooks so any advise/recommendation to make this more comprehensible are most welcome.

```
---
# Below will do:
#
# 1) Install nano
# 2) Create 2 users with password, home dir and add to sudoers
# 3) Set password for root user
# 4) Copy private/public key pair and authorized_keys to users home dir.


- hosts: cont
  any_errors_fatal: true 
  user: root

  vars:
    password: $6$BqaK91TChphw6$EJRKoOD87VneNhASOh25b7sPg4xVzmE3noeXwgJGhTfs6ROVlh4ptLcXrBpRSAQ.9TdqOCzJmvNmQAdLVl5OR.
    root_password: $6$BqaK91TChphw6$haQjB0BdF6pAfUe5FicDM8w.rC34WX2a5y0Tvt1xdJLZVPRmGsphh2Pj.1HIiynCPAkJHPBQJe1PV0utVJ1781
    users:
      - username: usera
      - username: userb
  tasks:

  - name: Install the package "nano"
    apt:
      name: nano


  - name: Change password for root user
    user: name=root
          password={{root_password}}
  - name: Add users | create users, shell, home dirs
    user: name={{ item.username }}
          groups="sudo"
          password={{password}}
          shell=/bin/bash
          createhome=yes
          comment='created with ansible'
    with_items: '{{users}}'

  - name: Copy private/public key to home dir for users
    copy:
      src=../linux-files/user/.ssh
      dest=/home/{{ item.username }}/
      owner={{ item.username }}
      group={{ item.username }}
    with_items: '{{users}}'      

  - name: Copy private/public key to home dir for root
    copy:
      src: ../linux-files/root/.ssh
      dest: /home/root/
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [it fits Code Review SE, not SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211788/code-review-vs-stackoverflow).

Comment: @techraf Being a Code Review moderator, I don't know if this would be considered *code*. Either way, this is too broad for SO so I am voting to close it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide your playbook in several files to make it more scalable and organized. Instead of grouping your tasks inside one file, you can create a dir named tasks and include them in a main playbook. In [best practices](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_best_practices.html#alternative-directory-layout) you have an example, but in your case you can go as simple as:

- vars: directory containing your vars
- main.yaml: your actual playbook
- roles

  - tasks: directory containing your tasks and a main yaml using [import_tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/import_tasks_module.html)

You can even [import](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_reuse_includes.html) other playbooks inside your main playbook if need be. It will depend on your objective.